# Programa que aumente el salario depende a los años o depende cuanto gane se le aumente o no

Tags: python

El programa consiste en que un empleado quiere saber si tiene posibilidades de un aumento o bonificación, entonces para esto hay varias condiciones:

1. si el sueldo del empleado no supera un millón, se le dará un 30% adicional.
2. si el empleado tiene hasta 10 años en la empresa, se le adicionan 500000 y si tiene más de esos 10 años se le adicionan 1000000.
3. Pero también hay más bonificaciones (Si su sueldo es mínimo un millón (que no supere los 2 millones) se le adicionan un 20%)
4. Si su sueldo es mínimo de 2 millones, incluso hasta 3 millones se le aportan solamente 10%
5. Y si su sueldo está por encima de los 3 millones pues no se le da nada

(YA LO HIZE)
**Python**

```
sueldo = float(input("Ingrese su sueldo "))
años = float(input("¿cuantos años tiene en la empresa? "))

total1=(sueldo*0.30)+sueldo
años10=500000
años11=1000000
total3=(sueldo*0.20)+sueldo
total4=(sueldo*0.10)+sueldo
total5=sueldo

if (sueldo<=1000000):
    if (años<=10 and años>0):
        print("su total es: ",total1+años10)
    if (años==0):
        print("su total es: ",total1)
    if (años>10):
        print("su total es: ",total1+años11)  
if (sueldo>1000000 and sueldo<=2000000):
    if (años<=10 and años>0):
        print("su total es: ",total3+años10)
    if (años==0):
        print("su total es: ",total3)
    if (años>10):
        print("su total es: ",total3+años11)  
if (sueldo<=3000000 and sueldo>2000000):
    if (años<=10 and años>0):
        print("su total es: ",total4+años10)
    if (años==0):
        print("su total es: ",total4)
    if (años>10):
        print("su total es: ",total4+años11)
if (sueldo>3000000):
    if (años<=10 and años>0):
        print("su total es: ",total5+años10)
    if (años==0):
        print("su total es: ",total5)
    if (años>10):
        print("su total es: ",total5+años11)
```

Comment: Yo queria poner el codigo pero no me da la opcion:(

Comment: No hay una opcion para eso. Tenes que copiar, pegar el código, y formatearlo com markdown. Si, editor antiguo...

Comment: Ahora no me deja hacer otra pregunta xd, gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Es que, no tendrias que hacer otra pregunta, si no editar la original.

Comment: Listo xd, Graciass

Comment: En la parte de los años, como que al final solo se va ha entrar en una de las condiciones, es mejor usar elif, es más eficiente. Si tienes 3 if seguidos el programa va a intentar entrar en los 3, los evalua todos, en cambio si tienes if elif elif intentará entrar en todos los que necesite hasta que se cumpla uno, una vez entre por el que toque ya no intentará entrar en los otros. Por ejemplo, si llevo 10 años en la empresa la condición que se cumple es la primera, pero igualmente va a intentar entrar en los dos otros if, cosa que no pasaría si fueran elif

Comment: Aquí hay una explicación sobre lo que te comento, por si no queda claro mi comentario: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo que no plantearía tu código con tantas variables, podrías tener una única e ir incrementadola según las diferentes condiciones.

Pero una cosa, creo que tus requisitos se solapan, por ejemplo tu primera condición habla solo de sueldo, pero la segunda habla de años.. ¿qué pasa si mi sueldo no supera un millon y llevo en la empresa 20 años? ¿se me aumenta el sueldo un 30% (por tener menos de un millon - condición 1) o se me aumentaría 1000000 al llevar en la empresa más de 10 años (condición 2)?

Teniendo en cuenta esto que te he comentado te propongo un ejemplo de código sobre lo que decía de las variables.

```
sueldo = float(input("Ingrese su sueldo "))
años = float(input("¿cuantos años tiene en la empresa? "))

total = sueldo;

#si el sueldo del empleado no supera un millón, se le dará un 30% adicional.
if (sueldo<=1000000):
    total = total+ (sueldo*0.3);

#si el empleado tiene hasta 10 años en la empresa, se le adicionan 500000 y si tiene más de esos 10 años se le adicionan 1000000.
if (anos<=10):
    total = total + 50000;
else
    total = total + 1000000;
    
#Si su sueldo es mínimo un millón (que no supere los 2 millones) se le adicionan un 20%
if (sueldo>1000000 and sueldo<=2000000):
    total = (sueldo*0.2);
    
#Y si su sueldo está por encima de los 3 millones pues no se le da nada --> esto sería un else seguramente
    
#mostrar resultado
print ("Su sueldo es:", total)
```

Comment: Uff, esta bueno, si me faltaron cosas, estaba feo mi codigo, hice uno nuevo y me funciona, muchas graciass